# Values become empty upon call to API POST from React JS Axios

Tags: mysql, reactjs, api, post, axios

I have an API TxnController, which accepts parameters @txnumber, @qnumber, @accountnumber, @amount, @emailaddress).

When using this sample string

```
{"txNumber":"1-202042121323","qNumber":65,"accountNumber":"12","amount":"12","emailAddress":""}
```

I was able to save this using POSTMAN.

BUT when I use the code below to call the API POST using Axios:

```
let onestr=[];
onestr=JSON.stringify(apostArray[i]);
alert(onestr);
console.log(onestr);
//alert(JSON.stringify(onestr));

axios
    .post('https://localhost:44338/api/txn/',{onestr})
    .then(response => {
        alert("POST SUCCESS "+response);
        alert("POST RESPONSE.DATA "+response.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        alert("POST ERROR "+error)
    })

}
```

I get empty values.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure it's the same uri? i find it hard to believe that your localhost is working under https

Comment: The API and react are on the same machine.